# Is there a more efficient way to calculate powerful numbers?

Tags: c++, optimization

I am trying to create an efficient function to generate a vector of all [powerful numbers](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Powerful_number) up to some `bound` (eventually I would like this bound to be as high as 10^17 or 10^18, which I think is within the max value of a 64-bit unsigned long long value - 2^64 - 1).

The most efficient method I have come up with is posted below. My question is only whether anyone has a better/more efficient suggestion.

When this function is executed, I have available a vector of primes up to the same bound; I considered using this vector in calculating powerful numbers, but at time of writing I thought the shown solution would be more efficient.

```
std::vector<int> powerful(int bound){
    int x,y,cnt,num;
    std::vector<int>* pows =  new std::vector<ull>;
    for(int i = 4; i<bound;i++){
        x = i;
        y=3;
        cnt = 0;
        num = x;
        while(x%2==0){
            x/=2;
            cnt++;
        }
        while ((y <= x) && (cnt != 1)) {
            cnt = 0;
            while (x % y == 0) {
                x /= y;
                cnt++;
            }
            y += 2;
        }
        if(cnt>1)
            pows->push_back(num);
    }
    return *pows;
 }
```

Comment: This question should probably go on code review instead of stack overflow.

Comment: @Hawkings I don't think so as they do not want their code reviewed but want a better implmentation

Comment: What do you mean by "more efficient"? Use less memory? Be faster? Use less CPU?

Comment: You do not need primes up to the same bound as the powerful numbers.  You need only primes up to its square root.

Comment: By "more efficient" I mean mostly faster execution time. And @John Bollinger I know, but the primes vector I have before this function is executed is up to the same bound

Answer (score 3):

Here's a recursive+iterative solution that builds powerful numbers from their constituent primes:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <vector>

static const int bound = 1000;
static const std::vector<int> primes =
    // I'm assuming you can create this by Sieve of Eratosthenes or similar
    { 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, };  // up to sqrt(bound)

typedef std::vector<int>::const_iterator prime_iter;

void add_powerful(std::set<int>& p, int v,
                  prime_iter it, prime_iter end, int bound)
{
    if (it == end) { // terminate the recursion
        p.insert(v);
        return;
    }

    add_powerful(p, v, it+1, end, bound);
    for (v *= *it * *it;  v <= bound;  v *= *it)
        add_powerful(p, v, it+1, end, bound);
}

int main()
{
    auto p = std::set<int>{};
    add_powerful(p, 1, primes.begin(), primes.end(), bound);
    for (auto i: p) std::cout << i << std::endl;
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

`add_powerful` recurses through the primes, in each case multiplying `v` by all the powers 0,2,3,4,... (omitting 1) of that prime.

My quick test agrees with the [expected results](https://oeis.org/A001694) up to 1000.

Comment: Ah okay, I also misunderstood your comment; I like this solution. Generating a primes table is no problem. Thank you!

Comment: This appears to be giving the right answers, but it looks like it may have trouble scaling.  Do you agree that it it goes to an ultimate recursion depth equal to the number of primes in the prime list?  For upper bounds in the area the OP mentioned, that could be in the hundreds of millions.  It's unlikely that many systems supply stacks that can handle that depth.

Comment: Correction: around 50 million for a powerful number bound of 10^18, but that's still way too deep.

Comment: @John, yes, you're right. it recurses as deeply as the prime vector is long.  Conversion to a completely iterative approach is left as an exercise...  I still think it's likely to be a better approach than factorising every integer in the target range, though.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to reverse-engineer a number to determine if it's a powerful number, generate powerful numbers using the known formula: `m = a^2 * b^3` (from your link)

You can increment the values of `a` and `b` to reach full coverage of all results less than N.

Comment: Yes, but you will compute a lot of duplicates this way, at least if you implement it naively.  It's not immediately evident how you would make this efficient.

Comment: I feel like combinations of powers of primes might be slower as the bound grows because of the number of possible prime factors. I was thinking that instead of incrementing y by 2 each time, covering odd factors, step y through the primes vector instead. I will try both ways. Thank you everyone for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way to approach this, in terms of minimizing the number of operations, is to generate the desired powerful numbers via their prime factorizations.  Prime factorizations are unique, and they tell you directly whether a number is powerful.  Given a list of the primes less than or equal to the square root of the upper bound on your powerful numbers, it is possible to systematically generate all distinct combinations of prime factors that yield an in-range powerful number.